# SELECT until endless in LibreOffic Calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I am used to `=COUNTA(B3:B999)` and change it when the number of rows exceeds 999, but I was wondering whether there is an endless setting.

**Attempt**

`=COUNTA(B3:B)` did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following (B3 is used as the first cell in this example):

Get remaining rows from current cell to the end of the column:

```
65536-ROW($B$3)+1
```

Select range from current cell to the end of the column:

```
OFFSET($B$3,0,0,(65536-ROW($B$3)+1),1)
```

Then count:

```
=COUNTA(OFFSET($B$3,0,0,(65536-ROW($B$3)+1),1))
```

NOTE: If you are using LibreOffice Calc v3.3.3 or later, then use 1048576 instead of 65536

Comment: Since you seem to be using 65536 as the upper limit on the number of rows, what's wrong with the much simpler `=COUNTA(B3:B65536)`? I ask because I think I must be missing something.

Comment: `=COUNTA(B3:B65536)` works fine until you start deleting rows in that range, when you delete rows the range will shrink in your formula

Comment: Also `=counta(indirect("B3:B65535"))` works - note that later Excel versions has 1M (2^20) rows, not only 64K (2^16).

Comment: OK, thanks. I've tested and found that the 2^20 limit mentioned by @Hannu also applies to LibreOffice, so you can use up to `=COUNTA(B3:B1048576)`. That means you would need over a million line deletions before the formula change becomes a problem. But I'm glad to have been made aware of the effect.